# Is there an application that can sort image files by creation date?

Tags: nautilus, files, thunar, photo-management

I'm searching for a way to show and sort pictures according to the record date (not "last change" date), but I didn't find any non-terminal program.

It should be a file browser like the Windows Explorer. Neither Thunar nor Nautilus has this feature.

Edit: Shotwell seems to be the best solution

Comment: Possibly related to http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2064272

Comment: Have you not tried Shotwell, the photo manager? It's installed by default in Ubuntu, and has ability to organize photos by date they were taken.

Comment: shot shotwell and software mentioned in the link are mostly photo organization software, but it MUST be a "windows explorer". I want people to switch to Ubuntu and they don't like much changes. I always hear: "why can't I sort them according to record date, Windows can do this"

Comment: The why is because Window and Linux use different filesystems. Linux typically uses `ext4` . Adding such feature on the system level is no trivial task , which is still is being worked on.  There are other filesystems, I believe `zfs` that are used in I believe in Oracle Linux or IBM Linux . Those do have the  creation date feature.

Comment: @Serg and how is shotwell handling this?

Comment: @Motte001 shotwell isn't handling it , the disk system is handling. The disk is formated to ext4 filesystem, hence there's not a lot you can do to get the creation date. Trust me, I've spend extensive time trying to get answer, and given up

Comment: @Serg I installed shotwell and it imported all pictures. And it did recognize the record date. So there must be a way to access these information

Comment: @Motte001 what type of image that is ?If that's `jpeg` , then it's possible to extract metadata from it. For most regular files, creation date is not possible to find

Comment: What about the Dolphin file manager?

Comment: @BharadwajRaju Dolphin has much more features of sorting than other, but also no record date

Comment: If Shotwell is your answer, why not add it as an answer...?

Comment: Some cameras/phones create file names containing the date and time. If this is the case for you, it is possible to create a shellscript, that uses the file name in order to create a system to sort the files according to creation date (for example by putting them into a directory structure based on `year/month/date`).

Comment: @Motte001 Dolphin does not have record date, but it has (file) creation date, which should be close enough.

Comment: "It should be a file browser" vs. "Shotwell seems to be the best solution" ?!?!

Answer (score 2):

### Nemo

Enable *List View* and then right click on the columns to add *EXIF Date*.

Answer (score 1):

[Digikam](https://www.digikam.org/) does what you want. Also I am pretty sure most photo management applications do. The creation date of a photograph is normally stored in its [exif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) data.

Dolphin has the ability to sort by file creation date (which is not the same as the exif record date). However, (as @Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy already noted) this has to be supported by the filesystem. Ext4 which I use does not.