# Sorting and using File creation dates

Tags: shotwell

I have a number of photos from different cameras and want to sort them in the sequence that they were taken ie Creation date and time. I only get Modified as an option.

Also, I edit my photos using Shotwell. Once a change is made to a photo I can no longer see the Creation date.

In summary the only date that I am ever interested in is the Creation Date and Time.

A solution may be to rename all the files including the date and time in the name!? But how??

It seems as though I found the solution thanks to the link and hints to use Shotwell. I previously edited the files by opening the file using Shotwell from "files", editing and "saving as", did not show original info. By rather viewing my pictures in Shotwell, it shows the folders that I have sorted the pics into, sorted by date and time, therefore showing the pictures taken by different cameras in chronological order. Editing and "exporting" the file retains the original info.

Comment: You'll probably need to use something that can access the files' metadata, rather than the regular filesystem 'stat' data - see [Is there an application that can sort image files by creation date?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768651/is-there-an-application-that-can-sort-image-files-by-creation-date)

Comment: Thank you for the link. The solution appeared to be Shotwell. It does sort the imported files by the time taken "Exposure Date and Time" however when the file is then edited it changes the date and time to the edited date and time, thus unfortunately still partly unhelpful.

Comment: Interesting. My normal editing procedure was to open pic in files using Shotwell and then to "save as". This results in exposure/created date not reflecting.  When opening and editing in Shotwell, there is no option to "save as" but an option to export. The edited file then opened in "Files" shows the correct original "Created on" date... hooray!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't say exactly which distro you are using. I am on 21.04 Xubuntu, so I will give you the answer here. I use Nemo as the file manager. With this I can right click in the header section, say just to the right of the "Name" field. This gives me a drop down of the columns I can display. There I see "Date Created".

Does that work for you?

Comment: After much searching I found "ubuntu-18.04"

Comment: Under Apps I searched for Nemo but it was not found

Comment: Why the down vote? Was what I said unhelpful, rude, or disparaging?

Comment: Thanks, I found Nemo and installed it. Unfortunately the "Date Created" is the date I modified the picture in Shotwell and not the date the picture was taken.

Comment: Apologies if I hit the down button accidently, I was not sure what all the buttons were...newbie... when i hit the up button it stays at -1

Comment: Ha!  Thanks Richard

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use `imagemagick`

You can install it with `sudo apt install imagemagick`, if it's not already installed on your system.

Then use the command `identify -verbose path/to/your/image` to get the metadata of your image.

You can also grep the result since you are only interested in the creation date and time. For example with `identify -verbose image.png | grep "date:create"`.

This way you'll get only the information you're interested in and can eventually reuse it in a script to rename your images, if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks i installed imagemagick. I do not like the way it operates, i prefer slides etc. It did keep the original "created date" after editing. When I edited with Shotwell and then reopened in imagemagick the created date is reflected as the date edited in Shotwell as well. So, so far not resolving my issue.